# Enabling MultiDex causes Gradle sync to fail

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-multidex

I followed the android developer website [instructions](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#mdex-gradle) for enabling MultiDex. But gradle sync fails when I add those lines. This is my `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.vvaezian.multilingovocabularypractice"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true    // <----- added ------
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField 'String', "ApiKey", MultiLingo_ApiKey
        }
        release {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            buildConfigField 'String', "ApiKey", MultiLingo_ApiKey
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'project.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2')

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.0'

    implementation('com.google.cloud:google-cloud-translate:1.3.1') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-translate:1.3.1'

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'  // <----- added ----
}
```

Also when I add `android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication` to manifest.xml it says `unresolved class 'MultiDexApplication'`, which I guess is because gradle sync failed.

I couldn't find the cause of failure of gradle sync in the logs:

```
2018-07-28 19:25:09,721 [e-1024-b01]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Started sync with Gradle for project 'MultiLingoVocabularyPractice'. 
2018-07-28 19:25:09,723 [e-1024-b01]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Consuming IndexingSuspender activation event: SYNC_STARTED 
2018-07-28 19:25:09,723 [e-1024-b01]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Starting batch update for project: Project '/local-scratch/vvaezian/AndroidStudioProjects/MultiLingoVocabularyPractice' MultiLingoVocabularyPractice 
2018-07-28 19:25:09,732 [ thread 26]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from /local-scratch/vvaezian/android-studio/jre 
2018-07-28 19:25:09,734 [ thread 26]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from /local-scratch/vvaezian/android-studio/jre 
2018-07-28 19:25:09,746 [ thread 26]   INFO - xecution.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line args to Gradle Tooling API: -Didea.version=3.1 -Djava.awt.headless=true -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only=true -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only.advanced=true -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only.versioned=3 -Pandroid.injected.studio.version=3.1.3.0 -Pandroid.builder.sdkDownload=false --init-script /tmp/ijinit.gradle 
2018-07-28 19:25:12,471 [ thread 26]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Started setup of project 'MultiLingoVocabularyPractice'. 
2018-07-28 19:25:12,472 [e-1024-b01]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Consuming IndexingSuspender activation event: SETUP_STARTED 
2018-07-28 19:25:12,494 [ thread 36]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Indexing suspended (context: Project Setup) 
2018-07-28 19:25:12,907 [e-1024-b01]   INFO - ule.android.SdkModuleSetupStep - Set Android SDK 'Android API 26 Platform (1)' (/local-scratch/vvaezian/SDK) to module 'app' 
2018-07-28 19:25:12,925 [ thread 37]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /local-scratch/vvaezian/SDK/build-tools/26.0.1/package.xml 
2018-07-28 19:25:12,933 [ thread 37]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /local-scratch/vvaezian/SDK/build-tools/27.0.3/package.xml 
2018-07-28 19:25:12,941 [ thread 37]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /local-scratch/vvaezian/SDK/emulator/package.xml 
2018-07-28 19:25:12,947 [ thread 37]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /local-scratch/vvaezian/SDK/extras/android/m2repository/package.xml 
2018-07-28 19:25:12,954 [ thread 37]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /local-scratch/vvaezian/SDK/extras/google/m2repository/package.xml 
2018-07-28 19:25:12,960 [ thread 37]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /local-scratch/vvaezian/SDK/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/constraint/constraint-layout-solver/1.0.2/package.xml 
2018-07-28 19:25:12,967 [ thread 37]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /local-scratch/vvaezian/SDK/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/constraint/constraint-layout/1.0.2/package.xml 
2018-07-28 19:25:12,974 [ thread 37]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /local-scratch/vvaezian/SDK/patcher/v4/package.xml 
2018-07-28 19:25:12,980 [ thread 37]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /local-scratch/vvaezian/SDK/platform-tools/package.xml 
2018-07-28 19:25:12,989 [ thread 37]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /local-scratch/vvaezian/SDK/platforms/android-23/package.xml 
2018-07-28 19:25:12,995 [ thread 37]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /local-scratch/vvaezian/SDK/platforms/android-24/package.xml 
2018-07-28 19:25:13,001 [ thread 37]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /local-scratch/vvaezian/SDK/platforms/android-25/package.xml 
2018-07-28 19:25:13,007 [ thread 37]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /local-scratch/vvaezian/SDK/platforms/android-26/package.xml 
2018-07-28 19:25:13,012 [ thread 37]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /local-scratch/vvaezian/SDK/sources/android-26/package.xml 
2018-07-28 19:25:13,017 [ thread 37]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /local-scratch/vvaezian/SDK/system-images/android-24/google_apis_playstore/x86/package.xml 
2018-07-28 19:25:13,022 [ thread 37]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /local-scratch/vvaezian/SDK/system-images/android-26/google_apis/x86/package.xml 
2018-07-28 19:25:13,033 [ thread 37]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /local-scratch/vvaezian/SDK/tools/package.xml 
2018-07-28 19:25:13,157 [ thread 35]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Gradle sync failed (3s 435ms) 
2018-07-28 19:25:13,167 [e-1024-b01]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Consuming IndexingSuspender deactivation event: SYNC_FINISHED 
2018-07-28 19:25:13,167 [e-1024-b01]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Finishing batch update for project: Project '/local-scratch/vvaezian/AndroidStudioProjects/MultiLingoVocabularyPractice' MultiLingoVocabularyPractice 
2018-07-28 19:25:13,173 [e-1024-b01]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - project roots have changed 
2018-07-28 19:25:13,242 [ thread 36]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Indexing released (context: Project Setup) 
2018-07-28 19:25:13,246 [e-1024-b01]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - project roots have changed 
2018-07-28 19:25:13,371 [ thread 36]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Clearing symbols finished in 0 s. 
2018-07-28 19:25:13,371 [ thread 36]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols in FAST mode, 0 source files from total 0 project files 
2018-07-28 19:25:13,413 [ thread 36]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading Module Maps finished in 0 s. 
2018-07-28 19:25:13,416 [ thread 36]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving Module Maps finished in 0 s. 
2018-07-28 19:25:13,416 [ thread 36]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving Module Maps finished in 0 s. 
2018-07-28 19:25:13,416 [ thread 36]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loaded 0 tables for 0 files (0 project files) 
2018-07-28 19:25:13,418 [ thread 36]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols for 0 source files 
2018-07-28 19:25:13,422 [ thread 36]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols for 0 unused headers 
2018-07-28 19:25:13,434 [ thread 36]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols finished in 0 s. 
2018-07-28 19:25:13,434 [ thread 36]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving modified symbols for 0 files (0 tables of total 0) 
2018-07-28 19:25:13,435 [ thread 36]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving symbols finished in 0 s. 
2018-07-28 19:25:13,505 [ thread 36]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 6ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2018-07-28 19:25:13,521 [ thread 36]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 15ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2018-07-28 19:25:13,521 [ thread 36]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Unindexed files update started: 2 files to update 
2018-07-28 19:25:13,571 [ thread 36]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Unindexed files update took 50ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you do not need to add android.support.multidex.MultidexApplication to your manifest file.
If you have any class which is extends Application there only you have to replace extends Application to extends MultidexApplication.

Comment: did you override Application class?

Comment: @masoudvali In the instructions it says if you haven't overridden Application class then add that line to manifest, otherwise do sth else. I'm not sure about overriding Application class. What does that mean? (btw I tried to sync without adding that line to manifest, but it didn't work either)

Comment: so I don't think that's the multidex problem. try setting specific version to this line `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'`

Comment: @masoudvali Interesting. When I replace `+` with what it suggested (1.0), gradle sync fails even when I do not enable MultiDex.

Comment: what was the error?

Comment: The log is similar to the one in the post, which is not very informative.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your gradle file is OK. You have to include  Multidex in your Application class:

```
public class YourApplicationClass extends Application {

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }

}
```

And In `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
 <application
    android:name=".YourApplicationClass"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="xyz"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: Please give more details. `YourApplicationClass` is my main activity? Or I need to create a new java class with this code?

Comment: It's a new Java class, Not your activity.

Comment: Gradle sync still fails.  In `MultiDex.install(this);` Multidex is red: `cannot resolve symbol MultiDex`